# Problem with Google Web Toolkit Maven Plugin

Tags: gwt, plugins, maven

I got an error following the [PetClinic GWT application in less then 30 minutes](http://www.dzone.com/links/r/create_petclinic_gwt_application_with_less_then_3.html) Any idea?

SOLVED after delete the C:\Users\user.m2 directory

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\petclinic>mvn -e gwt:run
+ Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building petclinic
[INFO]    task-segment: [gwt:run]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Preparing gwt:run
[INFO] [aspectj:compile {execution: default}]
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources,
i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
Downloading: http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/org/codeha
us/plexus/plexus-components/1.1.6/plexus-components-1.1.6.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-components:pom:1.1.6'
 in repository com.springsource.repository.bundles.release (http://repository.sp
ringsource.com/maven/bundles/release)
Downloading: http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/org/codeh
aus/plexus/plexus-components/1.1.6/plexus-components-1.1.6.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-components:pom:1.1.6'
 in repository com.springsource.repository.bundles.external (http://repository.s
pringsource.com/maven/bundles/external)
Downloading: http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/milestone/org/code
haus/plexus/plexus-components/1.1.6/plexus-components-1.1.6.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-components:pom:1.1.6'
 in repository com.springsource.repository.bundles.milestone (http://repository.
springsource.com/maven/bundles/milestone)
Downloading: http://maven.springframework.org/milestone/org/codehaus/plexus/plex
us-components/1.1.6/plexus-components-1.1.6.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-components:pom:1.1.6'
 in repository spring-maven-milestone (http://maven.springframework.org/mileston
e)
Downloading: http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/2.1.0.M1/gwt/maven/org
/codehaus/plexus/plexus-components/1.1.6/plexus-components-1.1.6.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-components:pom:1.1.6'
 in repository gwt-repo (http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/2.1.0.M1/g
wt/maven)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-components
/1.1.6/plexus-components-1.1.6.pom

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-components:pom:1.1.6

Reason: Cannot find parent: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus for project: org.codehaus
.plexus:plexus-components:pom:1.1.6 for project org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compo
nents:pom:1.1.6


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Unable to get dependency
 information: Unable to read the metadata file for artifact 'org.codehaus.plexus
:plexus-compiler-api:jar': Cannot find parent: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus for pr
oject: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-components:pom:1.1.6 for project org.codehaus.
plexus:plexus-components:pom:1.1.6
  org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-api:jar:1.5.3

from the specified remote repositories:
  com.springsource.repository.bundles.release (http://repository.springsource.co
m/maven/bundles/release),
  com.springsource.repository.bundles.milestone (http://repository.springsource.
com/maven/bundles/milestone),
  spring-maven-snapshot (http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot),
  com.springsource.repository.bundles.external (http://repository.springsource.c
om/maven/bundles/external),
  spring-maven-milestone (http://maven.springframework.org/milestone),
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  gwt-repo (http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/2.1.0.M1/gwt/maven),
  codehaus.org (http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org),
  JBoss Repo (http://repository.jboss.com/maven2)

Path to dependency:
        1) org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:1.3.1.google


        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(Defa
ultLifecycleExecutor.java:711)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandalone
Goal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(Defau
ltLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHan
dleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegmen
ts(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLi
fecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:6
0)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)

        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactResolutionException: Unabl
e to get dependency information: Unable to read the metadata file for artifact '
org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-api:jar': Cannot find parent: org.codehaus.p
lexus:plexus for project: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-components:pom:1.1.6 for pr
oject org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-components:pom:1.1.6
  org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-api:jar:1.5.3

from the specified remote repositories:
  com.springsource.repository.bundles.release (http://repository.springsource.co
m/maven/bundles/release),
  com.springsource.repository.bundles.milestone (http://repository.springsource.
com/maven/bundles/milestone),
  spring-maven-snapshot (http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot),
  com.springsource.repository.bundles.external (http://repository.springsource.c
om/maven/bundles/external),
  spring-maven-milestone (http://maven.springframework.org/milestone),
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  gwt-repo (http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/2.1.0.M1/gwt/maven),
  codehaus.org (http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org),
  JBoss Repo (http://repository.jboss.com/maven2)

Path to dependency:
        1) org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:1.3.1.google


        at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactCollector.recurse(D
efaultArtifactCollector.java:430)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactCollector.collect(D
efaultArtifactCollector.java:74)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveTra
nsitively(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:316)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveTra
nsitively(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:304)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.ensurePluginContainerIsC
omplete(DefaultPluginManager.java:835)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(Defaul
tPluginManager.java:647)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPlugi
nManager.java:468)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(Defa
ultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.metadata.ArtifactMetadataRetrievalException
: Unable to read the metadata file for artifact 'org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-comp
iler-api:jar': Cannot find parent: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus for project: org.c
odehaus.plexus:plexus-components:pom:1.1.6 for project org.codehaus.plexus:plexu
s-components:pom:1.1.6
        at org.apache.maven.project.artifact.MavenMetadataSource.retrieveRelocat
edProject(MavenMetadataSource.java:200)
        at org.apache.maven.project.artifact.MavenMetadataSource.retrieveRelocat
edArtifact(MavenMetadataSource.java:94)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactCollector.recurse(D
efaultArtifactCollector.java:387)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Cannot find parent
: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus for project: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-components:
pom:1.1.6 for project org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-components:pom:1.1.6
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.assembleLineage(D
efaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1396)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.assembleLineage(D
efaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1407)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.assembleLineage(D
efaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1407)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildInternal(Def
aultMavenProjectBuilder.java:823)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildFromReposito
ry(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:255)
        at org.apache.maven.project.artifact.MavenMetadataSource.retrieveRelocat
edProject(MavenMetadataSource.java:163)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.InvalidProjectModelException: Parse error re
ading POM. Reason: expected START_TAG or END_TAG not TEXT (position: TEXT seen .
..<role>Developer</role>\n      6878/?\r</... @163:16)  for project org.codehaus
.plexus:plexus at C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus\1.0.8\
plexus-1.0.8.pom
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.readModel(Default
MavenProjectBuilder.java:1610)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.readModel(Default
MavenProjectBuilder.java:1571)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.findModelFromRepo
sitory(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:562)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.assembleLineage(D
efaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1392)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException: expected ST
ART_TAG or END_TAG not TEXT (position: TEXT seen ...<role>Developer</role>\n
  6878/?\r</... @163:16)
        at hidden.org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.nextTag(MXParser.ja
va:1095)
        at org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader.parseDeveloper(MavenXp
p3Reader.java:1389)
        at org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader.parseModel(MavenXpp3Re
ader.java:1944)
        at org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader.read(MavenXpp3Reader.j
ava:3912)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.readModel(Default
MavenProjectBuilder.java:1606)
        ... 34 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Fri May 21 20:28:23 BST 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 45M/205M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Maven can't find the plexus artifact in one of it's known repositories. Are there any repositories in the pom.xml? Have you set up your distribution correctly? Which repositories do you have in your settings.xml?
You might want to try and add maven central to your settings.xml (http://repo2.maven.org/maven2)